# Finding application that is launching a command window regularly

Tags: windows

I have a problem with my Win10 PC where I'm getting regular command prompt windows launching every 15 mins or so, trying to run an app or batch file then disappearing so fast I can't see what was run.

Only started recently and I have not installed any new software, and my Windows defender is up to date so hopefully not a virus.

Also checked the various registry settings for startup apps
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
and Windows startup folder / Task Manager startup, nothing suspicious added.

I get these regular invocations even if there is no application running so its likely something in the background.

Any tips about how to locate what is being launched and by what app/background process?

Comment: I have a fast PC so the command window just flashes in a split second, too fast to even read what is being executed. Good idea about the event viewer but nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try a screen recorder and find out what is that first.

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/win-screen-recording-softwares/

sometime, you can't only rely on windows defender

try to run free software like Malwarebytes Anti-malware. sometime it sees what the best anti-virus software can't see.

you can also try this small software last activity view, which will show you the details of your computer's activity.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/lastactivityview.zip

Comment: Good idea, I'll run the recorder so that I can replay the split second the command window comes up then disappears.

Comment: Found it, thanks to the tip to run a screen recorder. Officebackgroundtaskscheduler.exe which is a Microsoft office bug apparently, fixed in the next office build. See here for details if anyone else is looking on superuser for a fix: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_officeinsider-mso_win10/officebackgroundtaskhandlerregistration-flashes-a/2600497e-78e4-41a1-9040-461cd2c3ea13